# How do I record musical notes as they are played with the Web Audio and Media Recorder api's?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, audio-recording

I'm trying to create a little app that records sounds from audio nodes as they are played using the Web Audio API, but have run into a few problems.

I have two buttons ('start recording' & 'stop recording') a media recorder and a `keydown` event listener attached to the window.

I don't want to record through the device's speaker but directly from `audioNodes`

**What I want to happen:**

1. When I click the 'start recording' button, the media player should start recording (which it does)
2. When I press key "1" the function `playNote` should play a sound.
3. When I click the 'stop recording' button, the media player should stop recording.
4. When I click the 'play' button on the media player, it should play back the note, or notes that have been played.

What's actually happening so far:

**Scenario 1:**

*Coded so the media player starts to record when the 'start recording' button is clicked*

1. I press 'start recording' and the media player starts recording.
2. I press key "1" and the `playNote` function does not run, I can hear nothing through the speakers.
3. I click 'stop recording' and the media player stops recording.
4. I click the play button on the media player and the media plays back a ***silent*** recording that lasts for the duration of the recorded session.

Result: The media recorder didn't record my sound!

**Scenario 2:**

*Coded so the media recorder starts recording when the `playNote` function runs:*

1. I press key "1" and the note plays and the media recorder starts recording.
2. I click the 'stop recording' button and the media player stops recording.
3. I click the play button on the media player and the recording is played back.

My problem with this second scenario is that I want to play more than one note/sound with successive keystrokes throughout the duration of the recording period so, starting the `startRecording` function in my `playNote` function does not achieve this, because as soon as key "1" is pressed again, a new sound and new  recording session are started.

So what I actually want to happen is this:

**Scenario 3:**

*Coded so the media recorder starts recording when the 'start recording' button is clicked:*

1. I click the 'start recording' button and the media player starts a recording session.
2. I press key "1" *a few times*, the notes played and recorded
3. I click the 'stop recording' button and the media player stops recording.
4. I click the play button on the media player and the recording is played back with all notes present

If anyone can help me solve this problem, I would be very grateful. The only way I can imagine getting this to work at the moment is to somehow create a `Blob` of each sound played and then chain them all together by pushing them into an array to play back the final recording.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to inject (for want of another term) outputs from `audioNodes` into an already running media stream? It would make life so much simpler! :-)

The code I have so far is below. If you comment out this line:

```
startRecording(); // If this isn't here, the note doesn't play when the media player has been told to start recording
```

You can see how **Scenario 1** pans out, as described above.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

```js
// Variables
let audioTag = document.getElementById("audioTag"),
  started = false,
  stopped,
  startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn"),
  stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn"),
  actx,
  recorder = false,
  recordingStream = false,
  mainVol;

// Define the global context, recording stream & gain nodes
actx = new AudioContext();

recordingStream = actx.createMediaStreamDestination();

mainVol = actx.createGain();
mainVol.gain.value = 0.1;

// Connect the main gain node to the recording stream and speakers
mainVol.connect(recordingStream);
mainVol.connect(actx.destination);

// Function to run when we want to start recording
function startRecording() {
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(recordingStream.stream);
  recorder.start();
  started = true;
}

// Function to run when we want to terminate the recording
function stopRecording() {
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    audioTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);

    recorder = false;
    stopped = true;
  };
  recorder.stop();
}

// Event listeners attached to the start and stop buttons
startBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (e) => {
    e.target.disabled = true;
    console.log("start button clicked");
    startRecording();
  },
  false
);

stopBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("stop button clicked");
  startBtn.disabled = false;
  stopRecording();
});

// A function to play a note
function playNote(freq, decay = 1, type = "sine") {
  let osc = actx.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = freq;

  osc.connect(mainVol); // connect to stream destination via main gain node
  startRecording(); // // If this isn't here, the note doesn't play when the media player has been told to start recording
  console.log(mainVol);
  osc.start(actx.currentTime);
  osc.stop(actx.currentTime + 1);
}

// keydown evennt listener attached to the window
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);

// The keydown handler
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "1") {
    console.log(e.key, "pressed");
    playNote(440);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="startBtn">Start Recording</button>
  <button id="stopBtn">Stop Recording</button>
</p>
<audio id="audioTag" controls="true"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! After a few days of unsuccessful research and hair loss, I had a thought! I have them occasionally ::oP

If we look at the code above we can see that we are creating a new `MediaRecorder` every time the `startRecording` function is called:

```
function startRecording() {
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(recordingStream.stream);
  recorder.start();
  started = true;
}
```

So I thought:

pull the recorder constructor out into the global scope

get rid of the `recorder = false` when `stopRecording` is called, so we can record again using the same `MediaRecorder` again if we wish:

```
function stopRecording() {
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    audioTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);

    //recorder = false;
    stopped = true;
  };
  recorder.stop();
}
```

Then, in our `playNote` function, add a conditional statement to only start the `MediaRecorder` if it is not already recording:

```
function playNote(freq, decay = 1, type = "sine") {
  let osc = actx.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = freq;

  osc.connect(mainVol); // connect to stream destination via main gain node

  // Only start the media recorder if it is not already recording
  if (recorder.state !== "recording") {
    startRecording();
  } // If this isn't here, the note doesn't play
  console.log(mainVol);
  osc.start(actx.currentTime);
  osc.stop(actx.currentTime + decay);
}
```

This works :-)

I also removed the `startBtn` and its event listener so that we don't accidentally press it and overwrite our recording.

And just for fun, added a new note to our `keyDownHandler`

```
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "1") {
    console.log(e.key, "pressed");
    playNote(440);
  }

  if (e.key === "2") {
    playNote(600);
  }
}
```

The final result is that we can now play notes repeatedly, stop recording when we are finished by clicking the `stopBtn` and then play back the recording by clicking the play button on the media recorder.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
// Variables
let audioTag = document.getElementById("audioTag"),
  started = false,
  stopped,
  //   startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn"),
  stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn"),
  actx,
  recorder = false,
  streamDest = false,
  mainVol;

// Define the global context, recording stream & gain nodes
actx = new AudioContext();

streamDest = actx.createMediaStreamDestination();

mainVol = actx.createGain();
mainVol.gain.value = 1;

// Create a new MediaRecorder and attached it to our stream
recorder = new MediaRecorder(streamDest.stream);

// Connect the main gain node to the recording stream and speakers
mainVol.connect(streamDest);
mainVol.connect(actx.destination);

// Function to run when we want to start recording
function startRecording() {
  recorder.start();
  started = true;

  console.log(recorder.state);
}

// Function to run when we want to terminate the recording
function stopRecording() {
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    audioTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);

    // recorder = false;
    stopped = true;
  };
  recorder.stop();
}

// Event listeners attached to the start and stop buttons
// startBtn.addEventListener(
//   "click",
//   (e) => {
//     e.target.disabled = true;
//     console.log("start button clicked");
//     startRecording();
//   },
//   false
// );

stopBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("stop button clicked");
  //   startBtn.disabled = false;
  stopRecording();
});

// A function to play a note
function playNote(freq, decay = 1, type = "sine") {
  let osc = actx.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = freq;

  osc.connect(mainVol); // connect to stream destination via main gain node

  // Only start the media recorder if it is not already recording
  if (recorder.state !== "recording") {
    startRecording();
  }
  osc.start(actx.currentTime);
  osc.stop(actx.currentTime + decay);
}

// keydown evennt listener attached to the window
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);

// The keydown handler
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "1") {
    console.log(e.key, "pressed");
    playNote(440);
  }

  if (e.key === "2") {
    playNote(600);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<h6>Keys #1 & #2 play sounds</h6>
<p>Recording starts when the first key is pressed</p>
<h6>Press the 'Stop Recording' button when finished</h6>
<h6>
  Click the play button on the media recorder to play back the recording
</h6>
<p>
  <!-- <button id="startBtn">Start Recording</button> -->
  <button id="stopBtn">Stop Recording</button>
</p>
<audio id="audioTag" controls="true"></audio>
```

So in the end, all we needed to do was:

create the `MediaRecorder` in the global scope

Start the `MediaRecorder` only if it is not already recording.